# Is it correct to place pagination on model in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

Hello I was refactoring some code but, I saw some methods that have the same implementation at this old app but I am not sure if I need to change the pagination to the controller or leave them on the model, what do you suggest?, example:

```
def self.the_method
  paginate :per_page => per_page, :page => page, :include => :other_model,
       :conditions => ["model_id > 0 AND time + interval '0.5 hour' ...
end
```

Comment: dose it still work from the model? i would suggest leaving it in the model if so

Comment: Yes it work well, but on the best practices I am not sure if it should be there

Comment: sorry it took so long for a reply.. busy day today.. i guess its your call, however i would typically keep it out of the controller.. thats just my preference.. i suppose best practice may dictate to put it in the controller but I've always kept that sort of logic in the model.. i suppose after reviewing items such as ransack and kaminari pagination it shows them putting it in the controller.